# what is wrong in my logic reversing vowels in a string?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, reverse

I tried solving a [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-vowels-of-a-string/) in leetcode 
which asks the programmer to reverse the vowels in the given string.
When I wrote my code in C, it ran fine and passed all the test cases.
I tried writing the same code in C++ but for a particular test case, it failed.

```
bool isVowel(char a)
{
    if(a == 'a' || a == 'e' || a == 'i' || a == 'o' || a == 'u')
        return true;
    if(a == 'A' || a == 'E' || a == 'I' || a == 'O' || a == 'U')
        return true;

    return false;
}

class Solution {
public:
    string reverseVowels(string s) {
        int i, j, k;
        int len = s.length();
        j = s.length() - 1;
        i = 0;
        k = 0;
        string result;
        //char result[len];
        if (j < 0)
            return s;
        while(j >= 0) {
            if (isVowel(s[j])) {
                result[k] = s[j];
                k++;
            }
            j--;
        }
    k = 0;
    j = s.length() - 1;

    while (i <= j) {
        if(isVowel(s[i])) {
            s[i] = result[k];
            k++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return s;
   }
 };
```

For some reason, when the input is "A new order began, a more Roman age bred Rowena." there is an error message AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ffd4a543ab0 at pc 0x000000405efb.
When I tried to debug, I found that, the first while loop gets infinite. But when I replace the string result to char result[len], my code is working fine.

What is wrong in my approach?
Thanks
hago

Comment: I recommend that you create a small `main` function which creates an instance of your `Solution` class and calls its `reverseVowels` function with the string you claim cause problems. Then you can easily use a debugger to catch the crash when it happens, and locate where in your code it happens.

Comment: when you reach this line `result[k] = s[j];` how many elements does `result` have? What is the range of valid indices?

Comment: A hint though: When you create a `std::string` object without specifying a size, then it's *empty* and all indexing will be out of bounds.

Comment: Just wonder: why did you make `class Solution`? It has only one function and no state.

Comment: @passing_throughare you asking me? No, I did not make that class. the skeleton was there already.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Well when I change the statement result [k] = s[j]; 
to 
result  += s[j];
the code is passing every testcase. So, how can I specify a string whose length is taken from another variable? 
For example in my case,
string result length should be the length of the input string at most.

Comment: There's an overloaded [`std::string` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) taking the size as argument. So you could do e.g. `string result(s.length());`.

Comment: `char result[len];` is not legal C++ code, and is a very bad idea in C. What would happen if your program got a string of one billion characters? You should think about reversing the vowels without allocating any arrays. That would be a valuable exercise.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Nope. I tried that already and got an error message as follows:
error: invalid conversion from 'std::basic_string<char>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct but with a simple mistake.

When you declare `string result;` then this variable is declared with 0 size. So whenever you try to place character at some position (i.e result[0], result[1], ...) it finds that there is no allocated memory for this variable. So it throws error.

In stead of placing character to the `result`, you can add the character to this string.

So you can write `result = result + s[j];`

Code snap should be like this -

```
string result = "";
//char result[len];
if (j < 0)
    return s;
while(j >= 0) {
    if (isVowel(s[j])) {
        result = result + s[j];
    }
    j--;
}
```

But adding character to a string takes more run-time.

Besides this, you can also use `string.push_back()` to add a *single* character to a string. It's complexity is overall `O(n), n = length of the final string`.

```
string result = "";
//char result[len];
if (j < 0)
    return s;
while(j >= 0) {
    if (isVowel(s[j])) {
        result.push_back(s[j]);
    }
    j--;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may not use the subscript operator for an empty string to change its value.
So your program has undefined behavior.

Pay attention to that in any case you are not reversing vowels in a string. You are trying to create a new string with reversed vowels from a given string. But this is not the same thing.

I can suggest the following Solution.:)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

class Solution final
{
private:
    static bool isVowel( char c )
    {
        const char *vowels = "AEIOU";

        return  std::strchr( vowels, std::toupper( static_cast<unsigned char>( c ) ) );
    }

public:
    static std::string & reverseVowels( std::string &s )
    {
        auto first = std::begin( s ), last = std::end( s );

        do
        {
            while ( first != last && !isVowel( *first ) ) ++first;

            if ( first != last )
            {
                while ( --last != first && !isVowel( *last ) );
            }

            if ( first != last ) std::iter_swap( first++, last ); 
        } while ( first != last );      

        return s;
    }
};


int main() 
{
    std::string s( "I am trying to write a program in C++" );

    std::cout << s << '\n';

    std::cout << Solution::reverseVowels( s ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
I am trying to write a program in C++
i am tryong ta wreti o prigram In C++
```

Pay into account that the letter `'y'` is not included in the set of vowels.

Comment: Thanks. I am not proficient in C++ to understand the syntax but will do it. 
on the other hand, you mentioned "Pay attention to that in any case you are not reversing vowels in a string. You are trying to create a new string with reversed vowels from a given string. But this is not the same thing."

I would like to disagree here. My approach is to create another array which will hold the vowels in the reverse order. Then I traverse the input string to replace the vowels from those in the 2nd array. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @hago For starters the function gets an object of the type std::string by value. And in turn it returns a new object. Ti change the same string you have to pass the object by reference.